# How to get a non repeating employee/ manager table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: department table[![employee table]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqzTP.png)

[image]

I basically need to get the different managers for each department and list Alice as all of their bosses. Please help. 
This is what I have:

```
SELECT distinct WRK.EMP_NUMBER, WRK.EMP_FNAME as WORKER_NAME, 
BOSS.EMP_FNAME AS BOSS_NAME, BOSS.DEPT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE AS WRK, EMPLOYEE AS BOSS, DEPARTMENT 
WHERE WRK.BOSS_NUMBER = BOSS.EMP_NUMBER
```

Comment: The design is wrong as well, `DEPARTMENT` should have 1 record for each department and should be related to `employees` with `department_id` .

Comment: I think you should show us the tuple in DEPARTMENT.

Comment: Just uploaded a screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is with Hierarchical queries which is not supported out of the box in MySQL see http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ on how to implement it and the cool things you can do with it.

on the other hand if you only need the manager name regardless the hierarchy you can use IN or self join.

The query should be:

```
SELECT emp_name, department 
FROM employee 
WHERE emp_number IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT boss_number 
      FROM employee 
      WHERE boss_number IS NOT NULL)
```